# Python QT4 - time sleep

Tags: python, pyqt, delay, qtimer

I have a simple python qt4 code that prints the same label vertically. How can i delay (time.sleep) for 1 second, before the next print label?

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
       .....
       self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.praxis)       

       self.label_i = 0
       self.timer = QTimer(self)
       self.timer.timeout.connect(self.praxis)
       self.timer.start(1000)


    def praxis(self):

        self.lbl1_count = 119
        for i in range(10):
            self.lbl_1 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
            self.lbl_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, self.lbl1_count, 14, 34))
            self.lbl_1.setText(_translate("Form", "Something Text", None))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(16)
            self.lbl_1.setFont(font)
            self.lbl_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
            self.lbl1_count += 35

            self.label_i += 1
            if self.label_i >= 10:
                self.timer.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `QTimer` to trigger a function call after x amount of time.  It's better than using a `sleep` because it won't freeze the GUI and you'll see the updates as they happen.

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.label_i = 0
    self.timer = QTimer(self)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_label)
    self.timer.start(1000)

def update_label(self):
    # Your label updating code above
    ...
    self.label_i += 1
    if self.label_i >= 10:
        self.timer.stop()
```

This will create a `QTimer` that will call your update function ever second (1000 milliseconds).  In the function, it checks if the function has been called 10 times and then stops the timer.

Comment: I edited the code to understand better the structure. I append the QTimer but doesn't works.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to also say to remove the `for` loop in your update function.  The Qtimer is replacing it as a sort of asynchronous for loop

Comment: I posted all code of application and i hope to understand. I can't remove for loop because i need it to iterate line edits, labels etc.

Comment: The QTimer is doing the iterating now.  It calls your function 10 times, with a 1 second gap in between each call